# Google Reader Feed Import

Tags: jsonp, google-reader

I'm working on a social RSS reader website, and with the news that Google Reader is shutting down, we'd like to capitalize on that by providing a feature for users to automatically import their Google Reader feeds in the same way that they might import contacts.  I can't seem to find a good API for this.

The one solution I found, sending a request to http://www.google.com/reader/api/0/subscription/list, doesn't work, because we have to be authenticated to receive results.  This means that either the user sends their google accounts password to us, obviously unacceptable, or we do the request client side.  However, that API doesn't seem to support jsonp, and so we're unable to do a cross-site query.

Does anyone have any suggestions or links I've overlooked?

Comment: *sidenote:* Google is retiring Google Reader in July 2013

Comment: @ShivanRaptor That's the first line of his question...

Comment: If the user is already logged into google reader you can have them export a feed bundle and migrate that. Also, if you provide easy migration from Google Reader that's a big plus for users like me.

Comment: Benjamin: Yea, that's our fallback option, but the more seamless the transition, the more likely we are to keep the user. :) We're very small (<20 active users, most of them our friends and family) but JUST on the verge of our big publicity push, so this is a great opportunity for us, and the best way to capitalize on that is to have as seamless a transition as possible!  If you send me an email at pi@presseract.com I can get you a beta key! We'd love the feedback.

Answer (score 2):

I am working on similar feature for my app, and i got the list of all the subscriptions (using the following URL) making a GET call with the access_token obtained via authenticating user using OAuth 2.0 for google reader API.

https://www.google.com/reader/api/0/subscription/list?output=json&access_token=USER_ACCESS_TOKEN

Answer (score 1):

You can use OAuth so that users give you permission to execute that server side request on behalf of them.

If you are developing with Java you can use [readr](https://github.com/shakiba/readr) (a Google Reader client I have developed).

Comment: I'm operating under C#, so I unfortunately can't use your library.  Do you have any other information about using OAuth to make that request? I can't seem to find any indication online that such a thing is possible (It's one of the first things I looked for!)

Comment: I don't know about c# but if you don't use java, you can try it online with "google oauth playground".

Comment: You can use the Java library if you use IKVM.net :)
Give the tool a try!